# Documentation Analytics.js Segment.io

Tags: javascript, analytics, segment-io

The people at Segment.io did a great job in building **analytics.js**, making it easy to load lots of javascript snippets (Intercom, GA, Kissmetrics, and so on) via one single open-source javascript library.

Repository: https://github.com/segmentio/analytics.js

They do offer a hosted version, with a nice UI for enabling integrations, this is a paid product. However, *analytics.js is open source*, so you could also use it for free (as self-hosted solution).

**Too bad there's no good how-to-set-this-up documentation available.**

There are some blogs about this, but these are out-dated:

- https://content.pivotal.io/blog/how-to-use-analytics-js-to-fix-your-analytics-code-and-achieve-metrics-nirvana
- [Issues with SegmentIO open source version setup of analytics.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23140113/issues-with-segmentio-open-source-version-setup-of-analytics-js)

Anybody who knows a place where we can find good docs on how to implement the open-source version analytics.js?

*If these docs just don't exist, we should start writing 'em, as it really makes a developers life way easier.*

Comment: I like the idea. I would like to not use their product, and a javascript library that would just forward and translate the calls to the js libraries of the other solutions (amplitude, analytics, kissmetrics). Any idea of a project like this?

Comment: @digao_mb - That's exactly how we use [analytics.js](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics.js)...

Answer (score 0):

The Analytics.js project README now has a link to the [Quickstart for Analytics.js](https://segment.com/docs/sources/website/analytics.js/quickstart/) document. That is a tutorial telling how to set up Analytics.js, so it seems someone else saw a need for this too.